# How do I set up a gateway through linux?

Tags: proxy, gateway

I want to create a linux gateway proxy for my wireless router. I have a modem connected to a non-wireless router connected to a wireless router set up as an access point. I want to put the linux server between the non-wireless router and the wireless router, so all traffic goes in one NIC and out the other. I'd like to be able to monitor the traffic. I'd also like to limit the amount of speed the wireless is allowed. The traffic should be mainly HTTP, so it won't matter too much if I can only monitor and reroute HTTP packets. I also want to be able to modify the pages it serves like inserting text in the page. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
modprobe ipt_MASQUERADE
iptables -F; iptables -t nat -F; iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j SNAT --to IP_EXTERN_OF_LINUX
```

MASQUERADE is used for dynamic ip address. If you have a static ip you can use SNAT (let me know)

Answer (score 0):

For the second part of your question, install a caching proxy like Squid on the box and set it up as a transparent proxy.

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-setup-transparent-proxy-squid-howto.html

You can then filter some or all requests and change them whichever way you want using a redirection script. For a funny but interesting example refer to:

http://www.ex-parrot.com/pete/upside-down-ternet.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you should go with ClearOS.

> ClearOS is a powerful network and
>   gateway server designed for small
>   organizations and distributed
>   environments.  Though ClearOS comes
>   with an extensive list of features 
>   and integrated services, the solution
>   is easy to configure thanks to the
>   intuitive web-based interface.

http://www.clearfoundation.com/